# Boostrap 4 spacing for mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap has spacing classes such as `m-sm-1` and `m-md-1`. It seems that it has for mobiles also as its written in its documentation: [Spacing utilities that apply to all breakpoints, from `xs` to `xl`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/). However, `m-xs-*` does not work. I could not find such a class in its source-code too

Does bootstrap 4 have spacing utility classes for mobiles?   How can I apply `mt-xs-2` on a button ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-xs-` variant was removed in Bootstrap 4 *everywhere*.  For most utility classes (as well as the Grid) behavior is as follows:

- `class-*`
- `class-sm-*`
- `class-md-*`
- `class-lg-*`

So for the Margin utility class you could do something like:

`<div class="m-1 m-sm-2 m-md-3 m-lg-4">Hi!</div>`

At the smallest breakpoint `m-1` would apply and it would work its way up from there.  You can learn more about this from the very same link in your original post:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

> The classes are named using the format **{property}{sides}-{size}** for xs
>   and **{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}** for sm, md, lg, and xl.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want for mobile only

Comment: @mahan - There is no such thing as 'mobile only'.  `m-1` applies to the smallest breakpoint (mobile) *and up* unless a larger breakpoint (ex: `m-md-1`) exists.

Comment: I have used `mt-3` together with  `mt-sm-0` and it seems that the element has `margin-top` on mobiles only.